# Given period and coefficients write the representation of the Fourier series for a continuous-time periodic signal

Tags: continuity, fourier-series, signal-processing

So I have to write $x(t)$ in the form:
$$
x(t)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} A_{k} \cos \left(\omega_{k} t+\phi_{k}\right)
$$

And I am told that $x(t)$ is real-valued and has a fundamental period $T=8$. Then I am given that the non-zero Fourier series coefficients for $x(t)$ are $a_{1}=a_{-1}=2, a_{3}=a_{-3}^{*}=4 j$.

Then my imediate thought is that $\omega_0=\frac{2\pi}{8}=\frac{\pi}{4}$ and I am thinking that I need to somehow cancel out the coefficients with the imaginary parts for $x(t)$ to be real valued. However, then I am completely lost how to proceed. I am also unsure what the star means in $a_{-3}^{*}$. I am thinking about convolution, but I am fairly new at convolutions and I find it odd that it is then $a_{3}=a_{-3}^{*}=4 j$.

Can someone help me understand how I am supposed to write this Fourier series?

Comment: I assume $j=-\sqrt{-1}$? I this case, the coefficients $a_k$ are the complex coefficients of the Fourier series $\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}a_ke^{i\omega_k t}$, and $a^*_j$ means the complex conjugate of $a_j$. (There's no convolution here.) $a_{-3}^*=a_3}$ guarantees that you get a real coefficient $A_3$ on the cosine term (well, perhaps it guarantees that the phase $\phi_3$ is zero). Anyway, just write out $\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}a_ke^{i\omega_k t} with the coefficients given and force it to look like the cosine expansion.

Comment: Yeah I got that I need to write a series, but I am still rather lost. First I need to figure $a_k$, but then I am also unsure whether I understood $\omega$. For $j$ it is just how engineers write imaginary numbers.

Comment: $\omega_0$ corresponds to the constant term, so that doesn't determine the fundamental period.  Instead, $2\pi/\omega_1$ is the fundamental period. Also, you are *given* the $a_k$'s, only four of which are non-zero, so you can write the series (as an expansion in complex exponentials) because there are only four terms, and then expand those exponentials in sines and cosines, rearrange, and then, at the end, if you have some sines, shift them (by adding $\phi_k$'s) to make cosines.